# Configurable smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Want to create marketplace where user can select smart contract template and configure it as per his/her requirements and generate decentralized application (dApps) over any blockchain.

Help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Did you finally get the answer??

Comment: @Mouazzam https://smartz.io this system is doing same thing for that I am looking for. Explore its source code.

Comment: Looks cool. Will go through the details. Thanks a ton